# apache ignite building in linux for c++

Tags: linux, ignite

while installation of apache ignite  (i am following DEVNOTES.txt)in this doc they mentioned steps to build,when i am doing 2nd step ./configure  it's giving error like bash: **./configure: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check that you're in the correct folder (`modules/platforms/cpp`). If this is the case, then most likely the first step failed and `configure` was not created. Check if there are any errors in the log.

Comment: i am in same path: /root/Desktop/Ignite/ignite-master/modules/platforms/cpp
[root@smsc cpp]# ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory    While first step i didn't see any errors but  configure is not created  it's created inside this folder ./autoconf-2.69/

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing "configure" file then there were error in previous steps or you are just didn't complete them all. Make sure you execute following commands one by one and not getting any errors:

- libtoolize
- aclocal
- autoheader
- automake --add-missing
- autoreconf

After you do that, if everything is OK, then "configure" file will be generated which you should execute:

./configure

Comment: if i am executing one by one step configure is generated,but while make its giving error like this  checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
./configure: line 2385: syntax error near unexpected token `yes'
./configure: line 2385: `AM_SILENT_RULES(yes)'
rm: cannot remove `core': Is a directory

Comment: @Yugandhar, May it be that you are using very old automake version? As far as I know, `AM_SILENT_RULES` macro [have been introduced in version 1.11](https://autotools.io/automake/silent.html)

Comment: Anyway, you can always just remove the `AM_SILENT_RULES([yes])` line from your `configure.ac` file as it only affects the output format during project building.